# ggplot2 - set lower bound greater than lowest point

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

For some reason the function I'm fitting with `ggplot2` is extending beyond the y-axis, even though the minimum value that can be obtained is zero. So, in attempting to restrict the lower bound to zero, I noticed that seemingly one cannot set only the lower bound such that data points are omitted (or predicted points, apparently). Is this true?

For instance, one can use `expand_limits` to zoom out, as it were:

```
require(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() 
p + expand_limits(y=0)
```

But one cannot zoom in:

```
p + expand_limits(y=15)
```

Same with setting the aesthetic:

```
p + aes(ymin=0)
p + aes(ymin=15)
```

I know I can use `ylim`, `coord_cartesian`, etc. to set *both* the upper and lower bound, but in this case, I'm passing a list to `ggplot` using `lapply` and the upper bound changes based on which object in the list is being plotted. So I'm back to plotting each object individually, which is very tedious. Any ideas?

EDIT: Hadley confirms this is not possible, so workaround by @Arun will have to do!

Comment: I can't seem to find it right now, but I feel certain this was discussed on the ggplot2 mailing list. My hazy recollection was that some people put forth the idea of allowing you to pass `Inf` or `-Inf` to `xlim` and `ylim` but that the actual implementation was much trickier than it seemed.

Comment: @jslefche, as a work around, can't you set it as `ylim(your_val, max(mtcars$mpg))`? (when you loop, you can pass that data's max value everytime..)? joran, are you sure it was for `xlim` and not for `geom_rect`?

Comment: @Arun I know Inf can be used in geom_rect, I just really feel like I remember this very request popping up on the mailing list, and some people suggesting that it would be nice if you could pass Inf and -Inf to xlim and ylim, and then Hadley or someone explaining that that would be nice, but very hard to implement.

Comment: @joran Is this what you're thinking of: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/s2kPtMUSS1U. Since the question is over a year old I was wondering if something had been implemented in the interim. Arun's Workaround may be my best shot though

Comment: Yes, that's it (along with the original discussion between Brian and Hadley that was the source of `expand_limits` in the first place). The only other option I can think of is to subset your data before passing it to ggplot.

Comment: @jslefche Can you provide more detail about your function?  This whole question sounds like a workaround and not a true solution to your fundamental problem.  When a plot doesn't show you the correct values, the first step is to verify the earlier steps and then evaluate the plotting method.  If you can share more info, I think we may find a more complete solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to plot the graphs, but if you can create a vector of the upper limit for each graph you could do something like this...

```
# Some vector of upper bounds for each plot which you can determine beforehand
ul <- c(20,25,30,35)
# Layout for printing plots (obviously you can handle this part however you like, this is just an example)
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

# Make some sensible number of rows/columns for plot page
x <- floor(sqrt(length(ul)))
y <- ceiling( length(ul) / x )

# Make list to hold plots
plots <- as.list( 1:length(ul) )
dim( plots ) <- c( x , y )


# Store plots with variable upper limit variable each time 
for( i in plots ){
        plots[[i]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()  + scale_y_continuous( limits = c( 15,ul[i]) , expand = c( 0 , 0 ) )
}


# Print the plots
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(x, y)))
for( i in 1:x){
    for( j in 1:y){
        print( plots[[ i , j ]] , vp = vplayout( i , j ) )
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @jslefche Is this what you were hoping to do?